# X-pack installation error in Kibana 5.2

Tags: elasticsearch, window, kibana, xpack, elasticsearch-x-pack

I have install elastic search 5.2.0 working fine,

when i am trying to install X-pack to kibana

```
....\bin> kibana-plugin.bat install x-pack
```

after restarting my Kibana.bat file(..\kibana-5.2.0-windows-x86\kibana-5.2.0-windows-x86\bin)  getting following error ....

> [![**Unhandled rejection [illegalarguments_exception] no endpoint
>   or opeation is available at][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpfkI.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpfkI.png)

Refere following image for more details....

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhoF3.png]

Comment: Did you also install the [x-pack plugin on your ES server](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/5.2/installing-xpack.html)?

Comment: no I haven't. Is it required?

Comment: Yes, you need to!

Comment: yes, already done thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of x-pack was not installed in elastic search

Install X-pack on elastic as well then run kibana;

Run following command to bin directory of ES

```
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install x-pack
```

Comment: What if we want to install offline?

Comment: Just download x-pack zip file and install with following command.

elasticsearch-plugin install /setup/x-pack-5.0.0/elasticsearch

Comment: Please look out following link 
  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/5.2/installing-xpack.html